# What does the term "executable "mean in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I've created a bash script in nano for my controlled assessment at school and one of the tasks is to define the functions of the term executable, any help guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question "executable" is a file with execute permission. The execute permission grants the ability to execute the file.

You can set the execute permission with `chmod`, for example:

```
nano script.sh       // your script
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

In the first line I create the file using nano (i choose `nano` because I read you have used that). In the second line because I want run the script just created I must to allow it being executable. I can do it using the `chmod` program (you can learn more about `chmod` typing `man chmod`). So I set the execute permission using `chmod` with the `+x` option. Now I could check if `script.sh` has the execute permission with the command `ls -l script.sh`.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Mpac  staff  8456 31 Feb 12:00 script.sh
```

Finally, in the last line I run the script.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain each line this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As it relates to this question, it essentially just means it can be executed without specifying anything else about the program outside of the script. For bash you're going to want to specify the bash location in the shebang (*#!/path/to/bash*) in the first line of the file, and this is in turn used to execute it when the script is called. e.g.

```
$ printf "#%c$(which bash)\necho \"hello world\"\n" > test.sh
$ chmod u+x test.sh
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world"
$ ./test.sh
hello world
```